# Help in identifying source of an identity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, resource-recommendations, tensor-calculus

For the identity given below

\begin{equation}
\lambda^{ab}\left(\lambda_{ab,i}\right)=\frac{1}{\tau}\left(\tau_{,i}\right),
\end{equation}

where $\lambda_{ab}$ is the metric tensor and $\tau=\det\lambda_{ab}$. Is there a textbook or research paper available from which I can cite said identity?

Comment: Check this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/381358/

Comment: That's a weird notation you have there.